# Solr Export Using Streaming Expressions not working when query is having special characters like comma

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am running the following streaming expression

```
curl --data-urlencode 'expr=search(collection1, q="(text:("apple inc,ltd"))",              
                                   fl="id",
                                   sort="id asc",
                                   qt="/export")' http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/stream
```

above query is throwing the following error

```
"EXCEPTION":"invalid expression search(collection1,q=\"\"(text: (\"apple inc\",ltd\"))\",fl=\"id\",sort=\"id asc\",qt=\"/export\") - unknown operands found"
```

It is automatically splitting my query on comma. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the `"` inside the quotes for the `q` parameter that's fubaring the parsing? Try escaping them with \.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thank you. Yes, that is what causing the issue. Is there a way to tell curl to do this instead of doing this manually?

Comment: CURL can't automagically know what you want escaped or not, so no, there is no way to let curl do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't escape the quotes inside the quoted string, Solr will think that you're ending the parameter right there.

Use `\"` to escape the quotes:

```
expr=search(collection1, q="(text:(\"apple inc,ltd\"))"
```